# How to scale two objects to fit together

Tags: modeling

If I have a cylinder and a half-sphere, for example, like this:

[image: example]

Which is the best/quickest way to scale the half-sphere to match the size of the cylinder maintaining the shape of the half-sphere? So that when I bridge them together I get completely straight lines?

Comment: I edited the "weird results". Its just the half-circle resizing not the way I want or getting inmense. with the half-circle selected I tried (I think) all the snap options without effort.

Comment: Did you try setting Snapping to Vertex, Closest, pressing Shift+Z while scaling to scale by 2 axes only and hovering over corner vertex of the cylinder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming nothing is centered or aligned (but rotation is consistent), use ***Snapping >> Vertex >> Active***.

1.) Select a bottom vertex with which to align the half-sphere. <kbd>L</kbd> to select connected vertices.

2.) Drag it over to snap it to its "sister" vertex.

3.) Reselect the vertex and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to move ***Cursor to Selected***.  Change the ***Pivot Point*** to ***3D Cursor***.

4.) Now, select the opposite vertex (make active) and <kbd>L</kbd> to select connected vertices.

5.) Scale to "sister" vertex.

[image]