# vertexsnap while scaling

Tags: modeling

Good day,

https://drive.google.com/open?id=153IEoXAUd5Uj3sDxQpcS0oe2q4crb7xx

please take a look at the attached video.
With the faces selected I would like to scale the inner edgeloop (ring) to the outer edges of the cylinder. Selecting just the edges and scaling works, but I cannot get it to work with the faces selected. I would like to understand why. Let's assume the faces need to stay that size and therefore should not be deselected.

Comment: Hello :). This could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/156712/

Comment: They solved it by grabbing a vertex and snapping it. How do I scale the whole edge ring by grabbing a vertex and moving it?

Answer (score 0):

This gave me a hint:
[How to scale two objects to fit together](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87969/how-to-scale-two-objects-to-fit-together)

Widdle Blender needs an additional help by giving it an "active" vertex (selected faces to vertex selection, shiftselect 2x one of the edge vertices) and then scale with snap set to active.
For some reasons the simple snap: closest does not work...